# Abrir PDF de servidor web donde el directorio está con contraseña - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, android-intent

Estoy desarrollando una app móvil donde quiero leer un documento PDF de un servidor externo, la carpeta donde está almacenada dicho PDF tiene contraseña por lo que intento hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
URL2 = "https://servidor.com/carpeta/nombre.pdf";
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL2));
String basicAuth = "user" + ":" + "pass";
basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(basicAuth.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
bundle.putString("Authorization", basicAuth);
intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

***Cannot display PDF (nombre.pdf cannot be opened)***

¿Alguien sabe qué estoy realizando mal y puede ayudarme?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente, **no es posible "inyectar" un password a un archivo pdf protegido usando `ACTION_VIEW` de forma nativa.**

Tienes que usar otra opción, por ejemplo un visor el cual permita enviar el password para que los usuarios puedan visualizar el contenido del archivo. En mi caso yo uso actualmente [RadaeePDF](https://www.radaeepdf.com/download/download-android), este visor permite inyectar un password.